# Click browser permission popup in playwright without grantPermission

Tags: selenium, e2e-testing, testcafe, nightwatch.js, playwright

I'm trying to write test with playwright.
My app use camera and microphone. So, I grant them using `context.grantPermissions(['camera', 'microphone'])`. It works on chrome but, not firefox and safari. ([Not supported yet](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/7635))

So I'm trying to click permission popup manually.

[camera_permission_popup_safari_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gixOs.png) <- This is image of permission popup of safari.

Is there any way to do this?

If there is something that can do this not even playwright, please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: It's not possible to click this popup manually (since the popup is coming from the browser and not inside your web-page). I'd recommend to upvote the issue in the Playwright repo (https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/7635).

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem that playwright supports the grantPermission api in Firefox. But I have discovered that you can use Firefox user preferences to bypass the camera/microphone permission request.

```js
    {
      name: "firefox",
      use: {
        ...devices["Desktop Firefox"],
        launchOptions: {
          firefoxUserPrefs: {
            // use fake audio and video media
            "media.navigator.streams.fake": true,
            "permissions.default.microphone": 1,
            "permissions.default.camera": 1,
          },
        },
      },
    },
```